# Why didn't Hester Shaw just ask Shrike to kill Thaddeus Valentine?

Tags: plot-explanation, mortal-engines

In *Mortal Engines*, Hester Shaw runs away from Shrike's care once she found out that Thaddeus Valentine was in the area in order to attempt to assassinate him.

Why didn't she just ask Shrike to help her?